# Timestamp formatting

Tags: date, paw-app

I tried to use custom Timestamp formatting in Paw for a POST-request with a JSON body - but how can the date be formatted?

My goal is to format the date like this:

`2014-01-10 00:01:00`

I tried inserting this into Paw:

`YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss`

The date wouldn't even appear though....

[image]

Additionally (I'm not sure if related):
When I inserted the § sign I would get a formatted date-string like this: `Tue Jan 20 18:08:33 2015`

[image]

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: FYI, here's the doc we've added for the timestamps https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Timestamp_Dynamic_Value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C string containing any combination of regular characters and special format specifiers. Look the table http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ctime/strftime/  .[image: Simple usage strftime]

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know they used C-strings.

Comment: We've just added details about the Timestamp dynamic value in the doc https://luckymarmot.com/paw/doc/Timestamp_Dynamic_Value